# Systematic ANR msg's executing time is too long on OPPO A91, Android 11

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On the oppo device in the title and on other low-end Chinese devices, I have a strong delay between sending a notification and receiving it.
I'm working on a video door phone app and I need to receive notifications from sending.

Note: with a totally empty app that contains only the firebase service, I receive the notification in 1-2 seconds.

Useful information: to reproduce the problem I have to kill the app and lock the screen, in this situation I receive the notification after 25 seconds.

If the screen is unlocked or the phone is connected to a cable, I receive the notification after 5 seconds.

I don't know if this could be useful but we use Hilt extensively, maybe there's a problem in app initialisation?

By looking at the logs I see an ANR_LOG >>> msg's executing time is too long.

Full logs: https://pastebin.com/q820vFFs

Useful manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

```
<service
    android:name=".service.PushNotificationService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:directBootAware="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Firebase dependencies:

```
const val firebaseBom = "31.1.0"
```

```
implementation(platform(Deps.firebaseBom))
implementation(Deps.firebaseAnalytics)
implementation(Deps.firebaseCrashlytics)
implementation(Deps.firebaseMessaging)
implementation(Deps.firebaseDynamicLink)
implementation(Deps.firebasePerf)
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-directboot:23.1.0")
```

google-services version is 4.3.14

Can anyone help me please?

I tried to update dependencies, implemented direct boot aware and set notifications to high priority. Also set all permissions from the device and disabled battery saving

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Delays can be caused by many factors so there's a lot to unpack here. You've mentioned that you already tried using high priority since messages can be delayed due to Doze mode. Additionally, the app can hit Android's app standby bucket limits and will down-prioritized messages to normal priority if you're always sending high priority. It may also be another problem in the API calls or the FCM backend. It’ll be challenging to pinpoint or even narrow down what is the specific cause of the delay on a public forum without going into project-specific details. I would recommend reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they can offer personalized help.